# Swift Dynamic UIPickerView

Tags: swift, dynamic, components, uipickerview

I feel like I’m close because the below code works for static UIPickerViews, but I’m trying to dynamically setup my pickerview based on the 1st selection and I can’t wrap my mind around this despite reviewing tutorials and searching.  For example, if you select “Brown” in myPickerData only “Undergraduate” should display in myPickerData2 or if you select “Dartmouth”, you should only get “Undergraduate” and “MBA” and last if you select “Columbia” or “Harvard”, you get “Undergraduate”, “JD”, “MBA”.

```swift
var myPickerData = ["Select Your Dream College", "Brown", "Columbia", "Dartmouth",  "Harvard" ]

var myPickerData2 = ["Undergraduate", "JD", "MBA"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0 {
        return myPickerData.count
    }

    return myPickerData2.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if component == 0 {
        return myPickerData[row] as String
    }
    return myPickerData2[row] as String
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    uniSelected = myPickerData[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]

    collegeSelected = myPickerData2[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

     if component == 0 {

         let str = myPickerData[row]

         if str == "Brown" {

            myPickerData2 = ["Undergraduate"]
         }
         else if str == "Dartmouth" {

            myPickerData2 = ["Undergraduate", "MBA"]
         }
         else {

            myPickerData2 = ["Undergraduate", "JD", "MBA"]

         }

         pickerView.reloadComponent(1)

      }
      else {

         uniSelected = myPickerData[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]

         collegeSelected = myPickerData2[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
      }

}
```

//

This may contain duplicates but you can try it

```
let mainDic:[String:[String]] = ["Select Your Dream College":[],
                 "Brown":["Undergraduate"],
                 "Dartmouth":["Undergraduate", "MBA"],
                 "Columbia":  ["Undergraduate", "JD", "MBA"],
                 "Harvard",["Undergraduate", "JD", "MBA"]]
```

Then

```
myPickerData2 = mainDic[myPickerData[row]]!

pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
```

And use this in component 0

```
myPickerData = Array(mainDic.keys)
```

Make your dataSource is `mainDic` and deal with keys as `myPickerData` and currently selected key's value as `myPickerData2`

**Edit :** In `viewDidLoad`

```
myPickerData = Array(mainDic.keys)
myPickerData2 = mainDic["Select Your Dream College"]! // it's default or simply []
```

Comment: That’s very helpful and had thought that would be the way to go about it.  However, is there a cleaner/scalable way to do this?  I only listed 3 for each datasource Array and imagine that a bigger array would become a HUGE if statement.  IE, if I load 15 potential selections in myPickerData1, then the if else statement would become very cluttered.

Comment: Ok, a dict array makes sense, but what changes with my original func methods?  Trying to visualize how my original code will change.  Thx again!

Comment: init  **myPickerData**  and **myPickerData2** from **mainDic** ,,, see edit

Comment: Tried to implement your suggestion with the dictionary and ran into so many problems so going to just use your original if statement haaa